# Fuelphp Asset:: error

Tags: php, fuelphp

Just testing out Fuelphp..
was wondering if anyone is aware of the issue with Asset:: call
I implemented it in a template and got an error ( error view : 'url')
thanks

ps: I guess i need to set Asset::add_path(??) , I tried Asset::add_path('/assets/') but that didnt do it.

Answer (score 3):

Due to inaccurate documentation i had the wrong syntax from the example :

```
Asset::css('main.css')
```

the correct syntax is :

```
Asset::css(array('main.css'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is actually acurate now. And Asset::css('main.css') is also supported.